# Cannot convert value of type MultipartFile to String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, file-handling

When I added validation for field Name  I got an error:

Validation failed for object='item'. Error count: 1org.springframework.validation.BindException
Field error in object 'item' on field 'image': rejected java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Entity, class Item

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@NotBlank(message = "Введите наименование")
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@JsonIgnore
@Lob
@Column(name = "image")
private String image;
}
```

Main controller

```
@PostMapping("/items")
public String add(
    @Valid Item item,
    @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file,
    BindingResult bindingResult,
    Model model
) throws IOException {

if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
    Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);
    model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);
    model.addAttribute("item", item);
} else {
    if (file != null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
        byte[] data = file.getBytes();
        String imageString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
        item.setImage(imageString);
    }
    model.addAttribute("item", null);
    itemService.saveItem(item);
}
```

Comment: What is the HTML form being submitted? And I'm guessing you get this error before any of your method code gets to run? It sounds like there's an image field trying to be bound into the Item object, and its value isn't valid for it. (Which might be it being a String field, but being submitted as a MultipartFile?)

Comment: Yeah, I added html part to the question. But it works without errors when I delete validation and I don't edit field 'image' at all.

Comment: So you only add or remove the `@Valid`, correct? But it's clearly trying to automatically bind your form image field to the `Item.image` attribute. It looks like your method is trying to both bind request parameters to the Item object and handle the request parameters separately, which I don't think you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating new formParams (quite similar with entity Items with all validation parameters) and put this form as a parameter to the post method.

```
@PostMapping("/items/save")
public String add(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @Valid ItemInputParams formParams,
                  BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) throws IOException {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        Map<String, String> errorsMap = 
ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);
        model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);
        model.addAttribute("item", formParams);
        return initItems(null, model);
    }

    Item item = new Item();
    item.setName(formParams.getName());
    (...)

    MultipartFile file = formParams.getImage();
    if (file != null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
        byte[] data = file.getBytes();
        String imageString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
        item.setImage(imageString);
    }
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have an enctype in your form opening tag and also ensure the name in the request param is the same name in the form and in the database field